# Android. Количество View

Tags: android, warning

В моей xml используется более 80 вьюшек. И это не максимум, будет еще штук 40 думаю. Мне так удобней работать так, чтобы все было в одном файле. Но при достижении 80 вью начало появляться это предупреждение [image: варнинг]

Стоит ли переделывать весь Layout, разбивая его на маленькие, или на этот варнинг можно не обращать внимания и никаких серьезных последствий не будет ?
Доп вопрос: Составляя главный layout из маленьких(include, fragments) можно ли во все xml файлы обращаться из главного и единственного класса ? Просто при работе с фрагментами приходилось создавать новые, а хотелось бы все в одном уместить.

Comment: может проще списком сделать?

Comment: @Andrew что именно ?И, чего бы это тут ни касалось, не понял что за список

Comment: ознакомьтесь с ответом пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для большого количества `View` элементов нужно использовать `RecyclerView` или `ListView` иначе вы столкнетесь с проблемами производительности работы приложения.

> можно ли во все xml файлы обращаться из главного и единственного
>   класса ?

Можно. Но это считается плохим тоном у разработчиков. Один единственный класс усложняет читаемость кода.